# Inheritance and method calling

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

This is a small java program.

```
class Parent {
    String message = "parent";
    void say() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    String message = "child";
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.say();
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be ***child***, since the *Child* class inherits from the *Parent* class.
But the output of this code is ***parent***.
Why is this happening?